# Traefik dashboad is not showing when port 8080 is not open

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm learning traefik and I try to setup the dashboard without port 8080 open.

With the config below, I can access the dashboard.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:1.7.9-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"

[api]

[docker]
```

As soon as I remove the port 8080 from docker-compose.yml I can't access it anymore.

What are the missing parts to have this very simple setup working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marvin help, I made it:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:1.7.9-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
 [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[api]
dashboard = true

[file]
  [backends]
    [backends.traefik]
      [backends.traefik.servers.server]
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

  [frontends]
    [frontends.traefik]
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "traefik"
      [frontends.traefik.routes.traefik]
      rule = "PathPrefixStrip:/traefik;PathPrefix:/traefik"

[docker]
```

Going to yourdomain.tld/traefik shows the dashboard!

Answer (score 0):

The url of the dashboard is *{your ip}:8080* by default.

I think you may be mixing things up here : the entryPoints you modified is "http", and not "api". Thus with this conf, you still need to access the dashboard through 8080.

If you want to change this fact, add an entrypoint (eg "foo") for the api, and set up entryPoints.foo to the matching config.

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":8090"

  [entryPoints.foo]
  address = ":80"

[api]
entryPoint = "foo"
```

But as you can see, you loose the "http" default port... which is quite annoying. So, I think you may keep 8080 or switch to a less guessable one here.

This mainly comes from [this part of the doc](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/api/#address-port)

Comment: Thanks Marvin, is there a way to keep 80 for normal use, dashboard is still on 8080 and  a rule with Prefix: /dashboard to route to the dashboard?

Comment: That's a very good question... I tried some settings, but didn't manage to do it. Though, Birkhoff Lee seems to have managed it : https://blog.birkhoff.me/serve-traefiks-internal-dashboard-behind-traefik/ Maybe you'll be luckier than me with his example